# Post request not getting req.body

Tags: node.js, express, aws-serverless, serverless-framework-offline

I am trying to make a post request with Postman. The only thing that returns is the id made by uuidv4() all the other information for the JSON object is not there.
I have tried req.body and req.apiGateway.event.body with no luck.

This is my post request:

```
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
// const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require("uuid");

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// app.unsubscribe(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/inspections", async (req, res) => {
   const data = req.apiGateway.event.body;
  const params = {
    TableName: "inspectionTrackTable",
    Item: {
      id: uuidv4(),
      unitNum: data.unitNum,
      building: data.building,
      managed: data.managed,
      rental: data.rental,
      inHouse: data.inHouse,
      robeCount: data.robeCount,
      inspected: data.inspected,
      notes: data.notes
    },
  };
  try {
    await db.put(params).promise();
    res.status(201).json({ unit: params.Item });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: e.message });
  }
});
```

This is what I am entering in Postman:

```
{
    "unitNum": "007",
    "building": "A",
    "managed": true,
    "rental": false,
    "inHouse": false,
    "robCount": 0,
    "inspected": false,
    "notes": "this is a good unit"
}
```

I have now tried adding ...req.body to the item like this:

```
    Item: {
      id: uuidv4(),
      ...req.body
    },
```

The response I am getting from that is:

```
{
    "unit": {
        "0": 123,
        "1": 10,
        "2": 32,
        "3": 32,
        "4": 32,
        "5": 32,
        "6": 34,
        "7": 117,
        "8": 110,
        "9": 105,
        "10": 116,
        "11": 78,
        "12": 117,
        "13": 109,
        "14": 34,
        "15": 58,
        "16": 32,
        "17": 34,
        "18": 48,
        "19": 48,
        "20": 55,
        "21": 34,
        "22": 44,
        "23": 10,
        "24": 32,
        "25": 32,
        "26": 32,
        "27": 32,
        "28": 34,
        "29": 98,
        "30": 117,
        "31": 105,
        "32": 108,
        "33": 100,
        "34": 105,
        "35": 110,
        "36": 103,
        "37": 34,
        "38": 58,
        "39": 32,
        "40": 34,
        "41": 65,
        "42": 34,
        "43": 10,
        "44": 32,
        "45": 32,
        "46": 32,
        "47": 32,
        "48": 10,
        "49": 125,
        "id": "efb90ad4-f68e-4ea0-b55c-6a4f79e3a96c"
    }
}
```

I did not expect that...
My delete, and get requests are working I am having trouble with the put and post..

Comment: You called the wrong api.

Comment: hi, it should be `req.body`, and in Postman make sure you're using the correct content-type (application/json)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? It is saving to my dynamoDB but only the id number, none of the body...

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaĐinh Thank you for the suggestion but it does look like that is what my content-type is set to